# How do I create a nested json object from xml data in oracle

Tags: json, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml in my oracle DB to return individual json object. I have different xpath. I would like to extract data from oracle xml in a nested json format. I have multiple applicants in my xml data, I would like to extract the data as a nested json format to know what data belong to an applicant
Result format example

```json
{
  "loanApplication": {
    "applicantGroup": [
      {
        "applicant": {
          "birthDate": "1-1-1",
          "maritalStatusDd": "3",
          "languagePreferenceDd": "0",
          "assetTypeDd": [1, 6],
          "asset": [1500, 60000],
          "Liabilities": [500, 600, 400],
          "sumOfAsset": 61500,
          "sumOfliabilities": 1500
        }
      },
      {
        "applicant": {
          "birthDate": "2-2-2",
          "maritalStatusDd": "0",
          "languagePreferenceDd": "0",
          "assetTypeDd": [2, 6, 9],
          "asset": [5000, 20000, 100],
          "Liabilities": [500, 600, 400],
          "sumOfAsset": 25100,
          "sumOfliabilities": 1500
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

sample data from xml

```
WITH t( xml ) AS
    (
    SELECT XMLType('<loanApplication xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <applicantGroup>
         <applicantGroupTypeDd>0</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>1</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>1500.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>RayM</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>60000</assetValue>
          </asset>
         <liability>
          <broker>
          <liabilityAmount>9999999.8</liabilityAmount>
          <liabilityDescription>CI</liabilityDescription>
          <liabilityTypeDd>2</liabilityTypeDd>
         </broker>
        </liability>
      <employmentHistory>
        <income>
          <annualIncomeAmount>150000.0</annualIncomeAmount>
          <incomeAmount>150000.0</incomeAmount>
          <incomeDescription>income description</incomeDescription>
          <incomePeriodDd>0</incomePeriodDd>
          <incomeTypeDd>6</incomeTypeDd>
        </income>
      </employmentHistory>
      </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
      <applicantGroup>
        <applicantGroupTypeDd>1</applicantGroupTypeDd>
        <applicant>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>neweg</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>2</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>5000.0</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>Bay</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>6</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>20000</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <asset>
            <assetDescription>TDC</assetDescription>
            <assetTypeDd>9</assetTypeDd>
            <assetValue>100</assetValue>
          </asset>
          <liability>
        <broker>
          <liabilityAmount>9999999.8</liabilityAmount>
          <liabilityDescription>CI</liabilityDescription>
          <liabilityTypeDd>2</liabilityTypeDd>
        </broker>
        </liability>
        <liability>
        <broker>
          <liabilityAmount>9999999.8</liabilityAmount>
          <liabilityDescription>CI</liabilityDescription>
          <liabilityTypeDd>2</liabilityTypeDd>
        </broker>
        </liability>
        <employmentHistory>
        <income>
          <annualIncomeAmount>150000.0</annualIncomeAmount>
          <incomeAmount>150000.0</incomeAmount>
          <incomeDescription>income description</incomeDescription>
          <incomePeriodDd>0</incomePeriodDd>
          <incomeTypeDd>6</incomeTypeDd>
        </income>
        </employmentHistory>
       </applicant>
      </applicantGroup>
        </loanApplication>')
     FROM dual
    )
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT (        
            KEY 'Assets' value y.Assets
            ,KEY 'assetType' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( val) FROM   
        XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'),'/loanApplication/applicantGroup/applicant/asset/assetTypeDd'
        PASSING (EXTRACT(xml, '/loanApplication', 'xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1"') ) COLUMNS val INT PATH './text()') )
            ,KEY 'liability' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( val) FROM   
        XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'),'/loanApplication/applicantGroup/applicant/liability/broker/BorrowerLiabilityType'
        PASSING (EXTRACT(xml, '/loanApplication', 'xmlns="http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1"') ) COLUMNS val INT PATH './text()') )
    ) applicant
    FROM t,
    XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'), '/loanApplication/applicantGroup/applicant/asset'
          PASSING xml
          COLUMNS
                Assets INT PATH 'assetValue') y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with grouping by **`applicantGroupTypeDd`** in order to seperate innermost objects(**`applicant`**), and go on with suitable function(**`JSON_OBJECT`** or **`JSON_ARRAYAGG`**) to the topmost level such as

```sql
WITH t(xml) AS
 (SELECT XMLType(<yourXMLvalue>)
    FROM dual)
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'loanApplication' VALUE
                   JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'applicantGroup' VALUE
                               JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'applicant'
                                                         VALUE JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'assetTypeDd' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(assetTypeDd),
                                                                           KEY 'asset'       VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(assetValue),
                                                                           KEY 'sumOfAsset'  VALUE SUM(assetValue))))))
  FROM t,
       XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'),
                '/loanApplication/applicantGroup' PASSING t.xml COLUMNS
                applicantGroupTypeDd INT PATH 'applicantGroupTypeDd',
                asset XMLTYPE PATH 'applicant/asset') t1,
       XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.abcdef.com/Schema/FCX/1'),
                'asset' PASSING t1.asset COLUMNS 
                                                assetTypeDd INT PATH 'assetTypeDd',
                                                assetValue  INT PATH 'assetValue') t2
 GROUP BY applicantGroupTypeDd
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5f23289e74b6236ef5f7f8c666506636)</kbd>